# My hard drive is making a loud, high pitched noise and won't boot

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, windows-installer

My hard drive is making this really high-pitched noise when it starts to spin up. It was working fine and not making any weird sounds for the last year and a half. I have an MSI GF62VR 7RF Gaming laptop with a 1TB HGST 7K1000 HDD. Everything in this computer works. I'm currently using it with an old HDD so I can at least have something for school. But a couple days ago I was doing homework and a bug crawled across the wrist support area above the hard drive. Naturally, I killed the bug with my hand. But doing this caused my computer to freeze. So I turned the device off, powered it back on, and the noise started. I also got a black screen saying "No bootable device found" or something along those lines. At first I thought it was a fan issue, but I ran the hard drive on a computer that I know has no other issues and heard the same thing. I'm pretty certain it is done for, I just really want to know what happened to it and what all I could do to at least save it or back up its contents. I'll see if I can link an audio recording I have of the hard drive running.

Comment: Here's the link to the audio file I have: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x5tcKGUoyYS3OadAZMQUntYmpz9NnPgG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I could not here the high pitch - but that could just be me.  I suggest backing up the drive immediately while it is running and then replace it.

Comment: Get a new drive, salvage what you can get off the misbehaving one, and then (optionally) investigate what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Sure seems like you swatted your hard disk drive. An HDD has tiny moving parts kept from touching by a *very* thin layer of air, and if the read/write head breaks through the film, the results is a scratched disk, or worse, a ruined head.

You can try putting the disk in another PC or in an external enclosure to try to salvage data. As a last-ditch experiment, you can [try chilling it](https://www.quora.com/How-effective-is-putting-a-hard-drive-in-the-freezer) and using it immediately, but that is unlikely to help, and can lead to condensation damage.

Hopefully, you've saved data or made a disk image recently, because the odds are against you getting it working. If there is **very** important data, there are [disk recovery services](https://www.business.com/categories/best-hard-drive-recovery-services/). **N.B.** Commercial recovery attempts can be *very* expensive... a few hours of their time could probably buy a new computer.